# Python, Streamlit AgGrid add new row to AgGrid Table

Tags: python, pandas, graph, streamlit

I am trying to add a new row to an AgGrid Table using streamlit and python

At this point, I just want to add 1 or more new rows to the table generated by the AgGrid by pressing the "add row" button.

After pressing the "add row" button I generate a second table with the new row mistakenly, so I get 2 data-tables instead of updating the main table.

The initial data `df = get_data()` is been gathered from a SQL query. I want to add a new row and (for now) save it into a CSV file or at least get the updated DF with the new row added as an output and graph it

[image]

#### My current code

```
import streamlit as st

from metrics.get_metrics import get_data

from metrics.config import PATH_SAMPLES
filename: str = 'updated_sample.csv'
save_path = PATH_SAMPLES.joinpath(filename)


def generate_agrid(data: pd.DataFrame):
    gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(data)
    gb.configure_default_column(editable=True)  # Make columns editable
    gb.configure_pagination(paginationAutoPageSize=True)  # Add pagination
    gb.configure_side_bar()  # Add a sidebar
    gb.configure_selection('multiple', use_checkbox=True,
                           groupSelectsChildren="Group checkbox select children")  # Enable multi-row selection
    gridOptions = gb.build()

    grid_response = AgGrid(
        data,
        gridOptions=gridOptions,
        data_return_mode=DataReturnMode.AS_INPUT,
        update_on='MANUAL',  # <- Should it let me update before returning?
        fit_columns_on_grid_load=False,
        theme=AgGridTheme.STREAMLIT,  # Add theme color to the table
        enable_enterprise_modules=True,
        height=350,
        width='100%',
        reload_data=True
    )

    data = grid_response['data']
    selected = grid_response['selected_rows']
    df = pd.DataFrame(selected)  # Pass the selected rows to a new dataframe df
    return grid_response

def onAddRow(grid_table):
    df = pd.DataFrame(grid_table['data'])
    column_fillers = {
        column: (False if df.dtypes[column] == "BooleanDtype"
             else 0 if df.dtypes[column] == "dtype('float64')"
        else '' if df.dtypes[column] == "string[python]"
        else datetime.datetime.utcnow() if df.dtypes[column] == "dtype('<M8[ns]')"
        else '')
        for column in df.columns
    }

    data = [column_fillers]
    df_empty = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df.columns)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_empty], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    grid_table = generate_agrid(df)
    return grid_table

# First data gather
df = get_data() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start graphing
    grid_table = generate_agrid(df)
    
    # add row
    st.sidebar.button("Add row", on_click=onAddRow, args=[grid_table])
```

Comment: At the start you call `grid_table = generate_agrid(df)`, so table is written. When you press Add row, you call again `grid_table = generate_agrid(df)`. This is the reason why you have two tables. The solution is to only call `generate_agrid(df)` once.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample minimal code.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridOptionsBuilder, GridUpdateMode


def generate_agrid(df):
    gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
    gb.configure_selection(selection_mode="multiple", use_checkbox=True)
    gridoptions = gb.build()

    grid_response = AgGrid(
        df,
        height=200,
        gridOptions=gridoptions,
        update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MANUAL
    )
    selected = grid_response['selected_rows']

    # Show the selected row.
    if selected:
        st.write('selected')
        st.dataframe(selected)

    return grid_response


def add_row(grid_table):
    df = pd.DataFrame(grid_table['data'])

    new_row = [['', 100]]
    df_empty = pd.DataFrame(new_row, columns=df.columns)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_empty], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

    # Save new df to sample.csv.
    df.to_csv('sample.csv', index=False)


def get_data():
    """Reads sample.csv and return a dataframe."""
    return pd.read_csv('sample.csv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = get_data()
    grid_response = generate_agrid(df)

    st.sidebar.button("Add row", on_click=add_row, args=[grid_response])
```

##### Initial output

[image]

##### Output after pressing add row

[image]

##### sample.csv

```
team,points
Lakers,120
Celtics,130
```